# How to disable print screen option, save page as option and view page source option(ctrl+u) in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I created an online exam application in asp.net. I want disable print screen option, save page as option and view page source option(ctrl+u). Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

It requires JavaScript.

```
document.body.addEventListener( 'contextmenu', function( e ) {

    e.preventDefault();

} );
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b9GEY/)

Comment: Thanks for your response.Can you give one example.Because I am beginner for ASP.NET and its important to me.. Thanks..

Comment: Added fiddle. Check it out